# microservices failed when I create a new repository with @ResourceRestRepository

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices

**I HAVE TWO REPOSITORIES with @RepositoryRestResource, one that is UserRepository, everything works fine, but when I add the new RoleRepository at the same height, the authentication drops as soon as I delete the RoleRepository everything works fine again I leave my code so that you can help me thanks**

// addresses established in zuul

```
    spring.application.name=service-zuul-server
server.port=8090

#config for register client
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

##Config path dynamic
#ruta para user
zuul.routes.user.service-id=service-user
zuul.routes.user.path=/api/user/**

#path for oauth
zuul.routes.security.service-id=service-oauth
zuul.routes.security.path=/api/security/**
zuul.routes.security.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout: 9000
ribbon.ReadTimeout: 30000
##config Zipkin
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9411/
spring.zipkin.sender.type=rabbit
```

**The UserRepository interface is in user-service**

```
    package com.game.app.user.repository;
    import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
    import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
    import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;
    import com.game.app.common.user.domain.Usuario;
    
    @RefreshScope
    @RepositoryRestResource(path = "user")
    
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {
        // url=localhost:8090/api/user/user
        @RestResource(path = "find-username")
        public Usuario findByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);
    
        @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.userName=?1")
        public Usuario buscarPorUsername(String userName);
    
    }
```

**the other interface created and the reason for which the authentification is dropped**

```
@RefreshScope
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "rol")
public interface RolRepository extends JpaRepository<Rol, Long>{

}
```

**the access routes that settled in zuul**

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/security/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/user").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user/user").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/rol").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/user/{userId}").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
    }
```

**When I create the interface RolRepository, it always goes to this class and it no longer gives me access**

@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessErrorHandler implements AuthenticationEventPublisher {
private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationSuccessErrorHandler.class);
@Autowired
private UsuarioService usuarioService;
@Autowired
private Environment env;

```
@Autowired
private Tracer tracer;

@Override
public void publishAuthenticationSuccess(Authentication authentication) {
    if (!authentication.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(env.getProperty("config.security.oauth.client.id"))) {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String mensaje = "Success Login:" + userDetails.getUsername();
        System.out.println(mensaje);
        log.info(mensaje);
        log.info("Authenticated" + authentication.getPrincipal());
        Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findByUserName(authentication.getName());
        if (usuario.getUserAttempts() != null && usuario.getUserAttempts() > 0) {
            usuario.setUserAttempts(0);
            usuarioService.update(usuario, usuario.getUserId());
        }
    } else {
        String mensaje = "Failed in Authentication!";
        System.out.println("=========="+mensaje+"===========");
        log.warn(mensaje);
    }

}

@Override
public void publishAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationException exception, Authentication authentication) {
    String mensaje = "Error en el Login:" + exception.getMessage();
    log.error(mensaje);
    System.out.println(mensaje);
    try {
        StringBuilder errors=new StringBuilder();
        errors.append(mensaje);
        Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findByUserName(authentication.getName());
        if (usuario.getUserAttempts() == null) {
            usuario.setUserAttempts(0);

        }
        log.info("Intentos actual es de:" + usuario.getUserAttempts());
        usuario.setUserAttempts(usuario.getUserAttempts() + 1);
        log.info("Intentos después es de:" + usuario.getUserAttempts());
        errors.append(" - Intentos del login:" + usuario.getUserAttempts());
        if (usuario.getUserAttempts() >= 3) {
            String erroMaximosIntentos=String.format("El usuario %s des-habilitado por máximos intentos.", usuario.getUserName());
            log.error(erroMaximosIntentos);
            errors.append(" - " + erroMaximosIntentos);
            usuario.setUserEnabled(false);

        }
        usuarioService.update(usuario, usuario.getUserId());
        tracer.currentSpan().tag("error.mensaje", errors.toString());
    } catch (FeignException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        log.error(String.format("El usuario %s no existe en el sistema", authentication.getName()));

    }

}
```

}

**postman request**
***This request works if the RolRepository is not found, but when it is created it throws error***
//
http://localhost:8090/api/security/oauth/token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX35Z.png)

Comment: check if you are getting correct value in this line `if (!authentication.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(env.getProperty("config.security.oauth.client.id"))) {`

Comment: Before I call JpaRepositoy (Role, Long) I get this way it works as I had already mentioned and also a double call is made as you can see in the printout

Comment: =====================body of method publishAuthenticationSuccess================
========================================================================
===authentication.getName()->=========frontendapp
===env.getProperty()->=========frontendapp
info->.equalsIgnoreCase->=========true
==========Failed in Authentication!=============================
=========================================================

Comment: =====================body of method publishAuthenticationSuccess================
========================================================================
===authentication.getName()->=========admin
===env.getProperty()->=========frontendapp
info->.equalsIgnoreCase->=========false
=====================->condition if==========================->
body of if->===============false
Success Login:admin

Comment: but when I add the jpaRepository it results in this print

Comment: =====================body of method publishAuthenticationSuccess================
========================================================================
===authentication.getName()->=========frontendapp
===env.getProperty()->=========frontendapp
info->.equalsIgnoreCase->=========true
==========Failed in Authentication!=============================
=========================================================
info->else->.equalsIgnoreCase->=======true Error en el Login:null